# Timemillisecond to hh:mm:ss format in java

Tags: java, time

In my code, I am generating timestamps value that is long millisecond .I want to convert this to HH:mm:ss(600000  to 00:10:00),I want disply difference in hh:mm:ss format

```
String strstart = "8:30:00";
String strend = "8:40:00";

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
try {
    Date date1 = sdf1.parse(strstart);

    Date date2 = sdf1.parse(strend);

    long durationInMillis = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    System.out.println("durationInMillis---->" + durationInMillis);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I use bellow code and the output is `0:10:0` like this but i want the output like `00:10:00`

```
int seconds = (int) (durationInMillis / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((durationInMillis / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((durationInMillis / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

System.out.println(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
```

Comment: You are getting that because `int hours` value would be stored as 0 instead of 00. Instead of this follow this post [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237193/java-convert-milliseconds-to-date)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d%n", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

By the way, use `"HH:mm:ss"` as `h` is for the 12 hour format (AM/PM) and `H` for the 24 hour format - an interesting bug,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `printf` you can use the same as mentioned by *Joop Eggen*. If you want to store the same in another string you can use as below.

```
String output = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d%n", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("etc/UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf1.format(new Date(durationInMillis)));
```

Comment: if use this code means its not showing 5:40:00 like but i want 00:10:00,what i want means I want difference time and add to next time like 9:30:00