# SimpleDateFormat fails to format Date interval?

Tags: java, date, timezone

I try to format a time interval using SimpleDateFormat.

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DateFormatTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    long interval = 1000;
    System.out.println("Interval in millis: " + interval);
    System.out.println("Expected result: 00:00:01");
    System.out.println("Result using Date and SimpleDateFormat: " +
      sdf.format(new Date(interval)));
  }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
Interval in millis: 1000
Expected result: 00:00:01
Result using Date and SimpleDateFormat: 01:00:01
```

I am in GMT+1 time zone. But it should not be reflected in the result.

Of course it can be solved with System.out.printf, but what I am searching is the reason.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is for formatting Dates, not intervals, so what it actually prints is the correct time for 1000 milliseconds past the epoch for GMT+1.  You should set the timezone of the SimpleDateFormat to UTC

Comment: Also use "HH:mm:ss", not "hh:mm:ss" for 24 hour date format. hh is a bug with funny consequences.

Comment: There is a similar question where the System.out.printf solution is detailed: [Timemillisecond to hh:mm:ss format in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169873/timemillisecond-to-hhmmss-format-in-java/14169970#14169970)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am in GMT+1 time zone. But it should not be reflected in the result.

Then you should set the time zone in the `SimpleDateFormat`. `SimpleDateFormat` is doing *exactly* the right thing - it's formatting the instant in time (just after midnight **UTC** 1970) in the time zone it's working in.

To change the time zone, just use:

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("etc/UTC"));
```

It's not clear whether you should *really* be using `SimpleDateFormat` at all, though. You're not trying to format a date/time - you're trying to format an *interval*, given your variable name.

I suggest you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which has a *much* richer type system, and will allow you to express what you *really* want.

Also, if you *really* want to use `SimpleDateFormat`, you probably want to use `HH` instead of `hh` in your format string. (`hh` is a 12-hour value, 1-12. You want 00:00:01, not 12:00:01.) `hh` is rarely appropriate when you don't *also* have an am/pm designator in your pattern.

Comment: it is GMT not UTC according to the javadoc (although it seems to be the same for that specific date).

Comment: @assylias: UTC is a better expression of this, IMO - it's not tied to a place at all. It's *particularly* helpful to use UTC for the Unix epoch, as people will often assume that the UK was observing GMT at the start of 1970, when it actually wasn't. (There was an experiment with going to UTC+1.) I suspect the documentation is historical, but I think using UTC is generally clearer. Admittedly UTC was only introduced as a term later than 1970, but...

Answer (score 4):

> I am in GMT+1 time zone. But should not be reflected in the result.

What makes you think so? `new Date(0)` is at 00:00AM GMT on Jan 1st 1970. So it is at 01:00AM if your default timezone is GMT + 1.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought somehow that Date uses local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

## Wrong data type

You are using the wrong class. You are trying to represent a duration of milliseconds and a time-of-day. Neither fits the `Date` class. That class represents a moment (a date, with time-of-day, in context of UTC).

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Also, `java.util.Date` is a terrible class, designed by people who did not understand date-time handling. Now obsolete.

## *java.time*

The modern solution uses *java.time* classes.

### `LocalTime`

Specifically, [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) for a time-of-day using a generic 24-hour day, without a date, and without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

The start of a day for generic days is 00:00:00. We have a constant for that: [`LocalTime.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIN). But know that in various time zones, on various dates, the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ;  // 3:30 PM.
```

### `Duration`

To represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline, on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds, use `Duration` class.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMilliseconds( 1_000 ) ;
```

We can do math with date-time objects.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.MIN.plus( d ) ;
```

You should know that *java.time* classes use a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), much finer than the [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) used by the legacy date-time classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).