# Android Date returns wrong value

Tags: android

[image]

I have set the milliseconds to 1390773600 in the constructor which translates to Sun, 26 Jan 2014 22:00:00. But as shown in the screenshot I keep getting 1970-01-16. What's going wrong here?

Comment: convert milliseconds to date :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237193/java-convert-milliseconds-to-date

Comment: The code is hardly visible.

Comment: Right click on image 'Open Image in New Tab'. Click again to zoom in.

Comment: Too much of work, for helping someone!

Comment: Facepalm, thanks anyways. Found out what's wrong.

Comment: Next time paste the code in, don't use screenshots to represent text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't.

1390773600 *seconds* does; milliseconds are seconds * 1000.

- https://www.google.com/search?q=1390773600+milliseconds+to+days
- https://www.google.com/search?q=1390773600+seconds+to+days
- https://www.google.com/search?q=16096.9+%2F+365&oq=16096.9+%2F+365

Comment: But when I enter that time stamp in this http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm it converts correctly. I'm very confused now.

Comment: Client insisted it's milliseconds and kept sending seconds. O_@