# ParseException parsing string to date

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to parse a string to a date but it is throwing the exception  `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1409239380000" (at offset 13)`. Here is my code:

```
String text="1409239380000";
try{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date1=dateFormat.parse(text);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Error final:", e.toString());
   }
```

Comment: Well, `1409239380000` doesn't really follow the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`...

Comment: I know it but I don't how to change the format to the format that I have.

Comment: `1409239380000` is an `Unparseable date`, hence the `ParseException`. Now what's your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java convert milliseconds to date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237193/java-convert-milliseconds-to-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to parse anything. You can just create a new `Date`:

```
String text = "1409239380000";
Date d = new Date(Long.valueOf(text));
```

If what you are trying to do is to format the date in the way you specify, use `format()`:

```
String text = "1409239380000";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.valueOf(text))));
```

This prints

```
2014-08-28 17:23:00
```