# Java delete numbers behind comma

Tags: java

I want to calculate Days, Hours etc.

I want to make it like this:
184 Seconds / 60 = 3,0666666666667
Means 3 Minutes.
0,666666666667 * 60 = 4

So 184 Seconds are 3 Min. und 4 Seconds.
Now i dont know how to bring this into Java. I need a function to seperate the Pre-Comma Value from the After-Comma Value.

It's just a simple example. I want to do this with years,weeks,days and so on

Comment: It seems you are looking for modulo operator `%`

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237193/java-convert-milliseconds-to-date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237193/java-convert-milliseconds-to-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for modulo (reminder) operator %. Also there is no "after comma value" in integers words so `184 / 60 = 3` not `3.06666`.

```
int time = 184;
int minutes = time / 60;
int seconds = time % 60;
System.out.println(minutes + " minutes : " + seconds + " seconds");
```

Output: `3 minutes : 4 seconds`

---

You can also use `Period` from *JodaTime* library.

```
int time = 184;
Period period = new Period(time * 1000);//in milliseconds 

System.out.printf("%d minutes, %d seconds%n", period.getMinutes(),
        period.getSeconds());
```

which will print `3 minutes, 4 seconds`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `%`, `/`, and a little math:

```
int totalSeconds = 184;
int minutes = totalSeconds/60; //will be 3 minutes
int seconds = totalSeconds%60; // will be 4 seconds
```

Comment: that's not correct. totalSeconds%60 will return 4, and are therefor the seconds.